# How to create a null jQuery data item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("selector").data("name", null);
console.log($("selector").data("name"));
```

This prints `undefined`.

Is there anyway to instantiate a `null` item in the jQuery data object of an element, not an undefined one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and Your code works fine, You should check if your `$("selector")` exists

Answer (score 3):

Your code works well as @Sebastian Krysiak stated, check if the selector exists. See working snippet below:

```js
console.log("before: " + $(".selector").data("name"));
$(".selector").data("name", null);
console.log("after: " + $(".selector").data("name"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='selector' data-name='test'></div>
```

An example to demonstrate what happens if the selector does not exist, like in your case, it returns `undefined` (maybe you should say what is the type of the selector e.g. `class` - `.selector` or `id` - `#selector`):

```js
console.log("before: " + $("selector").data("name"));
$("selector").data("name", null);
console.log("after: " + $("selector").data("name"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='selector' data-name='test'></div>
```

Comment: The statement was not inside of a function so it was running before the document loaded, and hence the selector didn't exist yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#selector").data("name", null);
console.log($("#selector").data("name"));
```

Works just fine as is, your selector might not exist.

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eo32jjay/

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var aVariableValue = null;
    $("#myDiv").data("name", aVariableValue);
    console.log($("#myDiv").data("name"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your method should work, tho the element you are selecting must exists.

Look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsukrk9b/) to see it in action.

```
// Before
alert($('#elem').data('foo'));

$('#elem').data('foo', null);

// After
alert($('#elem').data('foo'));
```